# secure communication between two application

Tags: php, apache, http, post, get

I am just a fresher and being curious about the communication between two application.
I know it can be done using API and by sending the get or post parameter to submit data from one application to another. but the question is, lets say there are two functions and 3 scenario..

all is in php. this is the language which i am following ryt nw..

**function 1:**

```
function get($name){
   echo $name;
}
```

**function 2 :**

```
 function send(){
   get('rudra');
 }
```

**Scenario 1:**

if these 2 functions are in the same file then we can easily call ryt :)

**senariao 2:**

lets say these two function are in 2 seperate files

file1 has send function

and
file 2 has get function

then i can do it like this by including file 2

like this

```
include 'file2.php';

 function send(){
   get('rudra');
 }
```

**scenario 3 : this is the problem**

in this scenario lets say these 2 functions are in the two different application in the same computer.

then how we would do is buy using api calls using http protocol (get or posts method), but can't we do something like calling functions rather than going through all over the internet or LAN using ip protocols or without disturbing apache, just to call some function which is on my computer?

Comment: try oauth1.0 is highly secure if you don't have encryption problem

Answer (score 0):

Using API with HTTP protocol is standard process for communication between two application. This way, your applications wont break in future if both application moves to different server.

But if you are thinking to make application for your own application then you can use http:// localhost/app1) or http:// localhost/app2 for call. (You need to make required entry in etc.host for this. This way, it won't make any LAN or Internet call.)